# Getting values from JSON using Python

Tags: python, json, simplejson

While I am trying to retrieve values from JSON string, it gives me an error:

```
data = json.loads('{"lat":444, "lon":555}')
return data["lat"]
```

But, if I iterate over the data, it gives me the elements (`lat` and `lon`), but not the values:

```
data = json.loads('{"lat":444, "lon":555}')
    ret = ''
    for j in data:
        ret = ret + ' ' + j
return ret
```

Which returns: `lat lon`

What do I need to do to get the values of `lat` and `lon`? (`444` and `555`)

Comment: Your first example works for me.  What is the error it gives you?

Comment: (unrelated), your second loop can be written as `' '.join(data)`

Comment: Using GAE with Python 2.7 and Bottle, it gives me "INFO     2012-09-10 13:54:58,583 dev_appserver.py:2967] "POST /app/939393/position HTTP/1.1" 500 -" on GAE Log console

Comment: error traceback could be useful here, as the code in the first part is ok. it can't throw an error related to the question (for python 3.6 at least), error has to be in the import or function use (as return present)

Answer (score 140, accepted):

If you want to iterate over both keys and values of the dictionary, do this:

```
for key, value in data.items():
    print(key, value)
```

Answer (score 92):

What error is it giving you?

If you do exactly this:

```
data = json.loads('{"lat":444, "lon":555}')
```

Then:

```
data['lat']
```

**SHOULD NOT** give you any error at all.

Answer (score 21):

Using Python to extract a value from the provided Json

Working sample:

```
import json
import sys

# load the data into an element
data = {"test1": "1", "test2": "2", "test3": "3"}

# dumps the json object into an element
json_str = json.dumps(data)

# load the json to a string
resp = json.loads(json_str)

# print the resp
print(resp)

# extract an element in the response
print(resp['test1'])
```

Comment: data.json()['test1'] !!!!

Comment: @Sireesh Yarlagadda The code works if I put the JSON format inside the ```json.loads(...)```. But If I need to load the JSON file as a ```"myfile.json"``` with the related commands, it outputs an error.... What should I do??

Comment: Does anyone read my question?

Comment: import json

file_path = 'data.json'

with open(file_path, 'r') as file:
    data = json.load(file)

print(data)

Answer (score 6):

There's a Py library that has a module that facilitates access to Json-like dictionary key-values as attributes: [pyxtension](https://pypi.org/project/pyxtension/) and
[Github source code](https://github.com/asuiu/pyxtension)

You can use it as:

```
j = Json('{"lat":444, "lon":555}')
j.lat + ' ' + j.lon
```

Answer (score 5):

Using your code, this is how I would do it. I know an answer was chosen, just giving additional options.

```
data = json.loads('{"lat":444, "lon":555}')
    ret = ''
    for j in data:
        ret = ret+" "+data[j]
return ret
```

When you use "for" in this manner you get the key of the object, not the value, so you can get the value by using the key as an index.

Comment: iterating over keys and then getting the respective values from the dict is discouraged in python. use `for key, value in data.items():` instead. It is more readable and less error-prone (also more efficient if one would care about that)