# How to get a json value inside of another json in python?

Tags: python, json, loops

I am trying to get the `"id"` and `"phone"` values in the data out of this json:

```
  "status": "success",
  "data": {
    "id": "MertD43fdfdDdsjk",
    "countrycode": "GB",
    "country": "United Kingdom",
    "createdAt": 15534534000,
    "validUntil": 15534534000,
    "service": "gmail",
    "phone": "446576879809",
    "price": 0.21
  }
}
```

My current code is

```
json_data = json.loads(response.text)
    #print(json_data)
    values = json_data.items()
    #print(values)
    recieved = False


    for key, value in values:
        print(key, value)

        if key == "id":
            numid = value
            print(numid)
        elif key == "phone":
            phone = value
            print("Recieved the Phone Number - ",phone)
            recieved = True
        elif value == "Mobile number isn't received. Please try again":
            if recieved == False:
                getPhoneNumber()
```

I know I am only accessing `status` and `data` items and not the stuff inside of `data`.
Currently, I am receiving the JSON as a result of requesting from an API so the values are always different.

Comment: Please provide a [mcve], as well as the current and expected output.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If that's a pure JSON from an API, why not do this?

```
d = {
    "status": "success",
    "data": {
        "id": "MertD43fdfdDdsjk",
        "countrycode": "GB",
        "country": "United Kingdom",
        "createdAt": 15534534000,
        "validUntil": 15534534000,
        "service": "gmail",
        "phone": "446576879809",
        "price": 0.21
    }
}

print(d["data"]["id"], d["data"]["phone"])
```

Output:

```
MertD43fdfdDdsjk 446576879809
```

Answer (score 1):

No need for loops, you can access the data by the key;

```py
import json

json_string = '{"status": "success", "data": {"id": "MertD43fdfdDdsjk", "countrycode": "GB", "country": "United Kingdom", "createdAt": 15534534000, "validUntil": 15534534000, "service": "gmail", "phone": "446576879809", "price": 0.21 } }'
json_data = json.loads(json_string)
data_dict = json_data['data']

dataid = data_dict['id']
phone = data_dict['phone']

print(dataid)
print(phone)
```

> MertD43fdfdDdsjk
>
> 446576879809

[Getting values from JSON using Python](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12353373/5625547)

Comment: Don't use `id` as variable name, as this shadows the built-in `id`.

Comment: Thanks @baduker! I've improved my answer!

Answer (score 1):

`values` is a dict, you can direct access fields

```
numid = values['data']['id']
phone = values['data']['phone']
```

Answer (score 0):

1. Use requests module which provides more features of extracting text # pip install requests
2. In this module after getting a response try response.json
3. For eg: if the received data is

   ```
    d = {
        "status": "success",
        "data": {
            "id": "MertD43fdfdDdsjk",
            "countrycode": "GB",
            "country": "United Kingdom",
            "createdAt": 15534534000,
            "validUntil": 15534534000,
            "service": "gmail",
            "phone": "446576879809",
            "price": 0.21
        }
    }
   ```

   Then to access id and phone number:=>

   ```
    data['data']['id'] # or 'phone'
   ```