# How to get key values in a json object(Python)

Tags: python, json

This is my json :

```
{'1': {'name': 'poulami', 'password': 'paul123', 'profession': 'user', 'uid': 'poulamipaul'}, '2': {'name': 'test', 'password': 'testing', 'profession': 'tester', 'uid': 'jarvistester'}}
```

I want to get a list of all the values of name.
What should be my code in python

Comment: This is not json, this is python dictionary

Comment: there some accepted answere in : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12353288/getting-values-from-json-using-python

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`d.values` gives all the values, then you can get the attribute `name` of each value.

```py
d = {'1': {'name': 'poulami', 'password': 'paul123', 'profession': 'user', 'uid': 'poulamipaul'}, '2': {'name': 'test', 'password': 'testing', 'profession': 'tester', 'uid': 'jarvistester'}}

[i['name'] for i in d.values()]
```

```
['poulami', 'test']
```

Also note that `d.values` returns a generator and not a list so to convert to list use `list(d.values())`

Answer (score 0):

**That is not JSON format.** It is a Python Dictionary.

Iterate over the values of the dictionary(`d.values()`) and get the `name` from each item.

```
d = {'1': {'name': 'poulami', 'password': 'paul123', 'profession': 'user', 'uid': 'poulamipaul'}, '2': {'name': 'test', 'password': 'testing', 'profession': 'tester', 'uid': 'jarvistester'}}

names_list = []

for i in d.values():
    names_list.append(i['name'])
```

```
names_list = ['poulami', 'test']
```