# How can I get a string from JSON in Python?

Tags: python, json

I have this JSON content:

```json
{'status': '1', 'message': 'OK',
'result': {'LastBlock': '14934113', 'SafeGasPrice': '119', 'ProposeGasPrice': '119', 'FastGasPrice': '119',
'suggestBaseFee': '118.174590189', 'gasUsedRatio': '0.025821954106323,0.354559890356924,0.173050329701518,0.340210087647076,0.0269005272339711'}}
```

How I can get strings from `'result'`? I want to get `'SafeGasPrice'`

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to parse data in JSON format?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7771011/how-to-parse-data-in-json-format)

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12353288/getting-values-from-json-using-python

Comment: This isn't JSON. JSON uses only double quotes.

Comment: @PeterMortenson (Active Reading: tags)    :-)

Answer (score 0):

I first get the values from result:
`gas_unit_price = gas_unit_price.json()["result"]`
Second I get the string I need:
`gas_unit_price = gas_unit_price["FastGasPrice"]`

Answer (score 0):

```
import json
data = json.loads('{"status": "1", "message": "OK", "result": {"LastBlock": "14934113", "SafeGasPrice": "119", "ProposeGasPrice": "119", "FastGasPrice": "119", "suggestBaseFee": "118.174590189", "gasUsedRatio": "0.025821954106323,0.354559890356924,0.173050329701518,0.340210087647076,0.0269005272339711"}}')
SafeGasPrice = data["result"]["SafeGasPrice"]
print(SafeGasPrice)
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: If [it isn't JSON](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72565438/how-to-get-string-from-json-python/72565510#comment128209110_72565438), how would this work? Did you test it? What was the result?